# Understanding `FixedPoint`

Tags: functions

I understand that

```
FixedPoint[(# + 2/# )/2 &, 1.]
```

can be written

```
x[0] = 1; x[1] = 2;
x[k_] := N@(x[k - 1] + x[1]/x[k - 1])/2
x@5
```

but I don't understand how to interpret

```
CompositeP[n_Integer] := FixedPoint[n + PrimePi[#] + 1 &, n] - n
```

mathematically. How could it be rewritten using a recurrence relation? How would it be written in standard mathematical notation?

Comment: $\begin{align}x_0&=n\\x_{k+1}&=π(x_k)+n+1\end{align}$

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. great! so simple! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to document what @Guesswhoitis. said in coments,

\begin{align}x_0&=n\\x_{k+1}&=π(x_k)+n+1\end{align}

which can be written

```
CompositeA[n_Integer] := FixedPoint[n + PrimePi[#] + 1 &, n]
```

or

```
rr = 10^2; x[0] = 1; x[1] = rr;
x[k_] := PrimePi[x[k - 1]] + x[1] + 1
x@5
```

On a different note, the same goal can be accomplised with

```
CompositeB[a_, r_] := 1 + a + Fold[PrimePi[a + #1 + 1] &, -1, Range[r]]
```

where

```
comp[a_] := 1 +a +Fold[PrimePi[a + #1 + 1] &, -1, Range[Floor[Log[a]] + 4]]
```

seems to do the trick, where `Floor[Log[a]] + 4` is a rough (over) guess at number of iterations to make.

Comment: I think you should put more attention to wording. Those functions are not the same. Arguments provided for them are different things either. The only thing which is the same is the goal. Which still is arguable since in `FixedPoint` you don't have to know a priori how many iterations to make.

Comment: @Kuba ok, will update